# How do i import a XML into filemaker pro or MS Access?

Tags: xml, database, ms-access, import, filemaker

i have a set of XML files as well as a style sheet and schema that i wanted to import into either a filemaker pro database or MS access.  The problem is that every time i select the XML file to import and then the style sheet I get an error in attempting to import.
    Is there somewhere in either filemaker or access that i need to specify the Schema file?  Because i think that's what the problem might be.
Thanks

Style sheets is called spl.xsl

```
<!--

The contents of this file are subject to the Health Level-7 Public
License Version 1.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file
except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the
License at http://www.hl7.org/HPL/hpl.txt.

Software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS"
basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See
the License for the specific language governing rights and
limitations under the License.

The Original Code is all this file.

The Initial Developer of the Original Code is Gunther Schadow.
Portions created by Initial Developer are Copyright (C) 2002-2004
Health Level Seven, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Contributor(s): Steven Gitterman, Brian Keller

Revision: $Id: spl.xsl,v 1.52 2005/08/26 05:59:26 gschadow Exp $

Revision: $Id: spl-common.xsl,v 2.0 2006/08/18 04:11:00 sbsuggs Exp $

-->
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:v3="urn:hl7-org:v3" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="v3 xsl">
<xsl:import href="spl-common.xsl"/>
<!--  Where to find JavaScript resources  -->
<xsl:param name="resourcesdir">http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/spl/stylesheet/</xsl:param>
<!--
 Whether to show the clickable XML, set to "/.." instead of "1" to turn off 
-->
<xsl:param name="show-subjects-xml" select="/.."/>
<!--
 Whether to show the data elements in special tables etc., set to "/.." instead of "1" to turn off 
-->
<xsl:param name="show-data" select="1"/>
<!--  This is the CSS link put into the output  -->
<xsl:param name="css">
http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/spl/stylesheet/spl.css
</xsl:param>
<!--
 Whether to show section numbers, set to 1 to enable and "/.." to turn off
-->
<xsl:param name="show-section-numbers" select="/.."/>
<!--  Whether to process mixins  -->
<xsl:param name="process-mixins" select="true()"/>
<xsl:param name="core-base-url">http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/spl/core</xsl:param>
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bx_in_8GQ_x5MGNuQXlSbHJXRzA&usp=sharing

XML file sample:  there is only 1 file
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bx_in_8GQ_x5T3R4X2lXNzY0cXc&usp=sharing

Comment: "*I get an error in attempting to import.*" Why don't you post the exact error message you get. "*Is there somewhere in either filemaker or access that i need to specify the Schema file?*" No (at least not when you import into FileMaker). However, your XSLT stylesheet must transform the source XML into FileMaker's FMPXMLRESULT grammar. That's more likely where the problem might be.

Comment: The XML files im using are found here http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/downloadLabels.cfm

and the schema and style are here   

http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/preview/upload.cfm   so does that mean that i have to change the style sheet that they provide to be able to open these files and import into filemaker?

Comment: Please edit your question and include an example XML you are trying to import and the XSLT stylesheet you are using. I didn't see either in the links you have provided.

Comment: I just added them.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I meant include the actual code in the question. There are numerous documents in the links you have posted and I am not in the mood for a treasure hunt.

Comment: i placed the stylesheet above but i cannot paste the xml bc its too long but theres only one xml file in this folder https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bx_in_8GQ_x5T3R4X2lXNzY0cXc&usp=sharing and thats the one im trying to work with.  Thanks again

Comment: That's not really a stylesheet - more like a wrapper for several documents, one of which is the real stylesheet. However, the chances that the missing stylesheet is Filemaker-specific are practically nil. You will need to write your own, I am afraid. I have taken a look at the XML and this is certainly not going to be a simple task. Anyway, you need to start by identifying what exactly do you want to import to where (in terms of what in the XML will be a Filemaker record, and which data will go into which fields). Possibly you may need more than one stylesheet to import related data.

Comment: Ah that would make sense.  Since i have all of the stylesheets that the wrapper is referring to https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bx_in_8GQ_x5MGNuQXlSbHJXRzA&usp=sharing  is there a way to open them and covert them to a different format that i can then import into filemaker.  i was really looking to pull out all of the written  non code information from 60K of these xml files and put them into filemaker.

Comment: "*is there a way to open them and covert them to a different format that i can then import into filemaker.*" That's not possible. Same as it's not possible to convert an English-German dictionary to an English-French one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an XSLT stylesheet that you could use as your starting point. It creates a record (ROW) for each top-level `<component>` element in the `<structuredBody>` section. Then it gets the value from the `root` attribute of the `<id>` element of the `<section>` element.

This will be channeled to a FIELD named "RootID". You will see this field in the Filemaker's import dialog, and you will be able to map it to a field in the target table - same as importing from a "real" Filemaker file.

I suggest you play with this for a while and try to add more data to the import tree. Then, if you have more specific questions to ask, post them as they come. However, you will need to have some basic XSLT know-how in order to tackle this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3"
exclude-result-prefixes="hl7">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
<ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
<PRODUCT BUILD="" NAME="" VERSION=""/>
<DATABASE DATEFORMAT="" LAYOUT="" NAME="" RECORDS="" TIMEFORMAT=""/>

<METADATA>
    <FIELD NAME="RootID" TYPE="TEXT" EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" />
    <!-- add more fields here -->   
</METADATA>

<RESULTSET FOUND="">
<xsl:for-each select="hl7:document/hl7:component/hl7:structuredBody/hl7:component">
<ROW>
        <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="hl7:section/hl7:id/@root"/></DATA></COL>
            <!-- add more columns here -->
</ROW>
</xsl:for-each>

</RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```